# Populating Combo-box2 from value selected in combo-box1

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, combobox, oledb

First Combo-box has student admin numbers. When a number is selected the next combo-box should reveal the list of classes for that student. However when a value is selected the second combo-box doesn't show anything.

**AdminNo** is stored in both **Student** and **ClassEnrollment** tables in the database.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class AddReport
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\ProjectDatabase.mdb")
    Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

Private Sub btnReturn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnReturn.Click
    Me.Close()
    Startup.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub AddReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StudentNameAdd()
End Sub

Sub StudentNameAdd()
    cn.Open()
    daa.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select AdminNo from Student", cn)
    daa.Fill(dt)
    CBStudent.Items.Clear()
    Dim r As DataRow
    For Each r In dt.Rows
        CBStudent.Items.Add(r(0).ToString)
    Next
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub CBStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBStudent.SelectedIndexChanged
    dt.Reset()
    Dim StudentAdminNo As Integer = CBStudent.SelectedValue
    cn.Open()
    daa.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select ClassCode from ClassEnrollment Where AdminNo=" & StudentAdminNo, cn)
    daa.Fill(dt)
    CBClass.Items.Clear()
    Dim r As DataRow
    For Each r In dt.Rows
        CBClass.Items.Add(r(0).ToString)
    Next
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Any help pushing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about binding the DataTable to the ComboBox by setting the Combobox's DataSource property to the DataTable?

EDIT: i've tested your code and it works fine if you change

```
Dim StudentAdminNo As Integer = CBStudent.SelectedValue
```

to

```
Dim StudentAdminNo As Integer = CBStudent.SelectedItem
```

Comment: CBClass and CBStudent are the combo-boxes